# Creating a list from results returned by an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to take some code which I had made into a list with .get into something which utilizes ajax however I haven't been able to get the results to appear as a list on the page. This api has a list of nasa's facilities and their latitude and longitudes which is what I am trying to list here's the code.
This is the original code which uses the get method to make a list of facilities which works:

```
$(document).ready(function(r){
  $.get("https://data.nasa.gov/resource/placeholder",function(r){
    r.forEach(function(el){
     $("ol").append("<li>"+el.facility+el+"</li>");
     console.log(el.location.human_address);
```

And this is the new code I am trying to use:

```
    var fullurl = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/placeholder"
    function(r){
      $.ajax({
      url:fullurl,
      success:r.each(function(el)
      r.forEach(function(el){
       $("ol").append("<li>"+el.facility+el.location.latitude+el.location.longitude+"</li>");
       console.log(el.location.human_address);
       console.log(el);
})
)
}
})
```

Here is the html for both:

```
<h1>N.A.S.A facilities</h1>

  <ol>

  </ol>
<input type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" id="t">
<button id="g"></button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>

</body>
```

Comment: AJAX has nothing whatsoever to do with creating a list. Part of what you show, if it properly creates a list, has nothing to do with display. That part you need to show, too. [mcve]

Comment: I added my old code for when I was using the get method. Maybe that will clarify things more.

Comment: Nothing you show has anything to do with display, that is, HTML/CSS.

Comment: There is no css but I added the html so hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need something like this :

```
var fullurl = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/placeholder";

function makeList() {
    return $.ajax({
        'url': fullurl
    }).then(function(results) {
        results.forEach(function(el) {
            $("ol").append("<li>" + el.facility + ' ' + el.location.latitude + ', ' + el.location.longitude + "</li>");
        });
    });
}
```